# Difference between INADDR_ANY in Linux and Windows socket programming

Tags: linux, sockets, delphi, winsock, multicast

My Winsock Delphi application should listen on all network interfaces for multicast UDP/IP stream. It listened normally until I tried it on another PC with different network adapters' priority order.

Then I started to research problem and found on some forums that `INADDR_ANY` (or `0.0.0.0`) has different meaning in Windows and Linux:

- In Linux [it means "listen on all interfaces"](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~srini/15-441/F01.full/www/assignments/P2/htmlsim_split/node18.html) and for sending - send through default interface
- In Windows [it means "listen on default interface"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738695(v=vs.85).aspx) (`0.0.0.1` for second one). Citation: "If this member specifies an IPv4 address of 0.0.0.0, the default IPv4 multicast interface is used" - without mentioning whether it is for listening or for sending.

Could you confirm or deny this?

How to listen really on all interfaces?

Here is a little piece of my code:

```
TMulticastListener = class(TThread)
private
  mreq: ip_mreq;
  ............
end;

constructor TMulticastListener.Create;
var err: Integer;
    wData: WsaData;
    reuse: Integer;
begin
  inherited Create(true);

  err := WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), wData);
  if err = SOCKET_ERROR then begin
    // Tell the user that we could not find a usable Winsock DLL
    perror('WSAStartup');
    Exit;
  end;

  // create what looks like an ordinary UDP socket
  fd := socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if fd = INVALID_SOCKET then begin
    perror('socket');
      Exit;
  end;

  reuse := 1;

  // allow multiple sockets to use the same PORT number
  if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, Pointer(@reuse), SizeOf(reuse)) < 0) then begin
    perror('Reusing ADDR failed');
    Exit;
  end;

  // set up destination address
  FillChar(addr, sizeof(addr), 0);
  addr.sin_family := AF_INET;
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr := htonl(INADDR_ANY); // N.B.: differs from sender
  addr.sin_port := htons(HELLO_PORT);

  // bind to receive address
  if (bind(fd, addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) then begin
      perror('bind');
      Exit;
  end;

  // use setsockopt() to request that the kernel join a multicast group
  mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr := inet_addr(HELLO_GROUP);
  mreq.imr_interface.s_addr := htonl(INADDR_ANY); //inet_addr('0.0.0.0');
  if (setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, @mreq, sizeof(mreq)) < 0) then begin
      perror('setsockopt');
      Exit;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows and Linux actually behave the same regarding the use of `INADDR_ANY`.  The confusion here is because the two links you provide are being used in *different contexts*.

When using the `bind` function to bind to an address/port, specifying `INADDR_ANY` means that the socket will be able to receive packets on the given port from any interface.  However, doing so does **not** set up anything regarding multicast.

In the context of the `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` call to `setsockopt`, setting the interface to `INADDR_ANY` will have the system join the given multicast group on the default network interface.

The Linux link you gave refers to `bind`, while the Windows link refers to `setsockopt` and `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP`.

If you want to join the multicast group on all interfaces, you need to retrieve the list of interfaces on the system and join each one.  On Windows, the [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915(v=vs.85).aspx) function will give you the list of interfaces.
 On Linux, use the [`getifaddrs()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) function.

Here's an example of how to use the `GetAdaptersAddresses()` function in C:

```c
struct iflist {
    char name[50];
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    int isloopback;
    int ismulti;
    int ifidx;
};

void getiflist(struct iflist *list, int *len)
{
    IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *head, *curr;
    IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS *uni;
    char *buf;
    int buflen, err, i;

    buflen = 100000;
    buf = calloc(buflen, 1);
    head = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *)buf;
    if ((err = GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_UNSPEC, 0, NULL, head,
                                    &buflen)) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        char errbuf[300];
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, err,
                      0, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf), NULL);
        printf("GetAdaptersAddresses failed: (%d) %s", err, errbuf);
        free(buf);
        return;
    }
    for (*len = 0, curr = head; curr; curr = curr->Next) {
        if (curr->IfType == IF_TYPE_TUNNEL) continue;
        for (uni = curr->FirstUnicastAddress; uni; uni = uni->Next) {
            if (curr->OperStatus == IfOperStatusUp) {
                memset(&list[*len], 0, sizeof(struct iflist));
                strncpy(list[*len].name, (char *)curr->AdapterName,
                        sizeof(list[i].name) - 1);
                memcpy(&list[*len].sin, uni->Address.lpSockaddr,
                        uni->Address.iSockaddrLength);
                list[*len].isloopback =
                        (curr->IfType == IF_TYPE_SOFTWARE_LOOPBACK);
                list[*len].ismulti =
                        ((curr->Flags & IP_ADAPTER_NO_MULTICAST) == 0);
                if (uni->Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family == AF_INET6) {
                    list[*len].ifidx = curr->Ipv6IfIndex;
                } else {
                    list[*len].ifidx = curr->IfIndex;
                }
                (*len)++;
            }
        }
    }
    free(buf);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

your source is completely oblivious of the fact that the internet protocol itself does not know anything about "ports" and "interfaces", the aforementioned statement *("listen on all interfaces")* doesnt even make any sense, its completely made up **but** packets to broadcast addresses typically are routed onto multiple interfaces, more on this below:

`0.0.0.0` is a special, reserved IPv4 address called *"network identifier"* - in fact IPv4 adresses which end with `0` typically are reserved - [it is typically not usable except for broadcast and network purposes](https://serverfault.com/a/10989/67666).
Operating systems usually reserve `0.0.0.0` for broadcasts within one single [transport protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer)

Now : these broadcast addresses always receive broadcasts for one single transport protocol via the **default route** which may point to multiple *(or all)* network interfaces. What you probably were reading about is something completely different : **[Multicast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast)** - thats yet another can of worms, it is possible to send **singular** packets to multiple, **designated** receivers - Microsoft Windows has a default multicast route and Linux typically has to be configured for multicast in order to work (AFAIK) - but you dont want that.

**Conclusion** : for your purposes, `0.0.0.0` is identical on Windows and Linux - its a [broadcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcasting_(networking)) address for your chosen transport protocol, there is no difference